# Delete date from string date ( [dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss] using SED

Tags: regex, date, sed

I been fighting with this problem for several days.
I have an output from a program which I'm trying to parse.

The output is the log stream that in some records 2 dates are added.

An example:

```
[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] request.INFO: Matched route "home". {"route_parameters": "more data"
[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] request.INFO: Matched route "home". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"bla/bla/controller"},"request_uri":"http://local.myapp.com/"} []
[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] data.DEBUG: SELECT s0_.id AS id0, s0_.name AS name1, s0_.value AS value2, FROM table s0_ WHERE s0_.active = ? [true] []
[2023-01-27 17:21:42] data.INFO: Some logs only include 1 date with a different format
```

A regular regex like: `/\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\] /g` would match the first date (brackets included). But I found really complicated to translate into an expression that SED can understand.

I tried multiple solutions I found across SO and other sites.

The input should be something like this:

```
[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] a
[2023-01-27 17:21:42] b 
[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] c
```

And the expected output:

```
[2023-01-27 17:21:42] a
[2023-01-27 17:21:42] b 
[2023-01-27 17:21:42] c
```

I tried multiple expressions like:

```
echo "[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] something" | sed -e "s/\[[0-9]{2}-[A-Z][a-z]{3}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\] //"
```

or this:

```
sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\] $/\1/'
```

Which deletes the contents of the first date inside brackets, but I want to keep the 2nd date when the log only includes 1

I think I'm close, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

#### Answer

Really hard to decide who give it the answer. Both were really helpful, but I decided to go with the 1st one received, because was fast, and elegant. The 2nd one, I wish I could select 2 answers are valid. Took my approach and made a simple change... So I was really close.

Thank you all. :)

Comment: Where do a, b and c come from?

Comment: It's the output (Stream) from an old application (PHP-FPM)\, which Is really hard to update. :(

Comment: There is no `a or b or c` in `"[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] something"`

Comment: Not the answer you want but: fight the logging hell by making all facilities log their timestamps in the same way. Preferably in ISO-8901 format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
echo "[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2023-01-27 17:21:42] something" |
sed -E 's/^\[[^]]+] (\[[^]]+])/\1/'

[2023-01-27 17:21:42] something
```

**Break down:**

- `^`: Start
- `\[[^]]+]`: Match first `[...]` text
- : Match a space
- `(\[[^]]+])`: Match second `[...]` text and capture in group #1

Comment: Almost, the only issue with your solution, and perhaps I didn't explain it in a better way, is that I want to keep the `something` after the second group. Your solution is simple and elegant, :thumbs-up: but removes the rest of the text. Which only require to remove 2 chars. :D `'s/^\[[^]]+] (\[[^]]+])/\1/'`

Comment: Yes that's right, just removing `.*` takes care of that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You are not so far:

```bash
> echo -e "[27-Jan-2023 17:21:42] [2024-01-27 17:21:42] something\n[2025-01-27 17:21:42] something else" | sed -E "s/\[[0-9]{2}-[A-Z][a-z]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\] //"
[2024-01-27 17:21:42] something
[2025-01-27 17:21:42] something else
```

Replace a `{3}` by a `{2}` for the month abbreviation.

Comment: Amazing... but why 2 instead of 3? The month in the date is 3 chars in length?

Comment: First char: `[A-Z]`, second and third: `[a-z]{2}`